# PrimeNG Table ColGroup with dynamic headers and columns

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I m trying to achieve the dynamic headers and columns in primeng colgroup table.
There are examples for static colgroup table with static header and column.

Comment: With a quick search, I was able to find what you are looking for: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/dynamic Did you try to search?

Comment: Yes, i have seen the dynamic column and i have worked it, but its not available in colgroup (Column Group) for dynamic headers and columns

Comment: This you manage to do this @vivi2822?